# Convert time string/text to time (calculable)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a column of data which consists of strings such as follows:

**Row 1:** 46m 06s.

**Row 2:** 15d 5h 09m 33s

**Row 3:** 17h 24m 59s

Etc

I want to convert these strings to number or time format so I can perform calculations on them, but the current format makes various formula challenging to use. Ideas?

Comment: These are all really good ideas. I’ll test them out, particularly non-code ones since I need to keep the file simple for those who inherit the file later on

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Function convert_text_to_interval(interval As String) As Double
Dim temp() As String, tmp As Variant
On Error GoTo error_handler
temp = Split(interval)
For Each tmp In temp
    Select Case Right(Trim(tmp), 1)
        Case "d"
            convert_text_to_interval = convert_text_to_interval + Val(tmp)
        Case "h"
            convert_text_to_interval = convert_text_to_interval + Val(tmp) / 24#
        Case "m"
            convert_text_to_interval = convert_text_to_interval + Val(tmp) / 1440#
        Case "s"
            convert_text_to_interval = convert_text_to_interval + Val(tmp) / 86400#
    End Select
Next
Exit Function

error_handler:
convert_text_to_interval = 0
End Function
```

The function must be inserted into a common module (not to a sheet or class module!).

After insertion it will be available in formula master in User-defined functions section. Or it can be inserted directly (for example, as `=convert_text_to_interval(A1)`).

[image: usage]

The spaces between interval parts are compulsory (`1h30m` not allowed, it will be treated as `1m`, see below).

The unit letter must be adjacent to a value (`1 h 30 m` not allowed, it will be treated as `0h 0m`, see below).

The parts without correct unit letter are ignored. If unit part contains more than 1 letter, the last one is used, all another are ignored (`1hm` == `1m`). All non-digit symbols except the last unit letter are ignored.

Multiple parts with the same unit (`1h 15m 30m` == `1h 45m`) are allowed.

Fractional values (decimal separator - dot `.`) are allowed (`1.5h`). Negative values are allowed (`2h -20m` == `1h 40m`).

NumberFormat for a cell where this function is used can be both number and time (in last case recommended format is Cell.NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss" - it will not cut hours over a day, for example, `15d 5h 09m 33s` will be shown as `365:09:33`, not `5:09:33` as for "h:mm:ss" format).

Comment: Include an example that how to use the Function for example `=convert_text_text_to_interval(Cell refe)`.

Comment: Your code needs this corrections,,  `tmp As Variant` instead of `String` and `Case code should Case "h"` instead of  `Case 'h'`. Also what about the Format of the Formula Cell !!

Comment: *`Case` code should `Case "h"` instead of `Case 'h'`* Thanks, edited. *`tmp As Variant` instead of `String`* Edited too. *what about the Format of the Formula Cell* As user needed (maybe number, maybe time).

Comment: For this line ,,`dim temp() as string, tmp` it should `dim temp() as string, tmp as Variant`. And for the first example if Formula cell is Number the `Ans is Zero`,, if Time the is `12:07:00 AM` ,, I think it should `01:46:06 AM` instead.

Comment: @RajeshS *And for the first example if Formula cell is Number the Ans is Zero,, if Time the is 12:07:00 AM ,, I think it should 01:46:06 AM instead.* I cannot understand this phrase. And why `AM` - it is interval, not time.

Comment: For  `1: 46m 06s`,,  if Formula cell is `[H]:MM:SS` Answer is `0:01:06` if Cell has `Number Format` Ans is `0.00`. `HH:MM` ans is `00:01`.

Comment: *if Formula cell is [H]:MM:SS* maybe you mean cell format? *Answer is 0:01:06* See screenshot - `0:46:06` is shown...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90599/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-akina).

Answer (score 1):

#### Parses a String of text for 'd' 'h' 'm' 's' values and converts to time.

[image: sample data output]

This will not replace the string values. Instead, use this formula to create a helper column for the time arithmetic.

- To enable the display of over 24 hours in in the time formula cells, use the `[h]:mm:ss` time format.
- All value & letter pairs in the time string are optional. If the letter is present, the value must be attached.
- No space between value and unit letter `3h` not `3 h` (not: 3 space h)
- Separate one pair from the next with a space.  `3d 2h` (3d space 2h)
  This is an error: `3d2h` (if it has two digits, like the 11 in `3d11h`, it should be ok).
- The letters are case insensitive (e.g. 'h' or 'H').

**Multiline formatted formula: Paste directly into the formula bar

to avoid splitting the formula over multiple rows.**

```
=VALUE( IFERROR( LEFT( I11, SEARCH( "d", I11) - 1),0) * 24 +
IFERROR( IFERROR( MID( I11, SEARCH( "h", I11) - 2, 2), MID( I11, SEARCH( "h", I11) - 1, 1)), 0) & ":" &
IFERROR( IFERROR( MID( I11, SEARCH( "m", I11) - 2, 2), MID( I11, SEARCH( "m", I11) - 1, 1)), 0) & ":" &
IFERROR( IFERROR( MID( I11, SEARCH( "s", I11) - 2, 2), MID( I11, SEARCH( "s", I11) - 1, 1)), 0))
```

The value `I11` is the cell with the time string (search and replace).
- Or create (insert) helper column.
- Insert new row.
- Paste formula in new row in helper column.
- Cut cell I11 and paste in new row's time string column (assumes I11 is not referenced by an existing formula).
- Copy the contents of original I11 back to the formula bar of I11 so the relative addresses are not moved back, just the contents.

Comment: It's working,, now you get 10 ☺

Answer (score 0):

**Your issue can be solved by using few Helper Columns also:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Sample data in Range `A4:E29`.
- `D, H, M & S` indicates `Day, Hour, Minute & 
  Second`.
- Formula in **B4** & fill down:

  `=VALUE(IFERROR(LEFT(A4,SEARCH("d",A4)-1),0)*24)/24`
- Formula in **C4** & fill down:

  `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C$3,$A4)),MID($A4,IF(SEARCH(C$3,$A4)<5,1,SEARCH(C$3,$A4)-2),IF(SEARCH(C$3,$A4)<5,SEARCH(C$3,$A4)-1,2)),0)*1`
- Formula in **D4** & fill down:

  `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D$3,$A4)),MID($A4,IF(SEARCH(D$3,$A4)<5,1,SEARCH(D$3,$A4)-2),IF(SEARCH(D$3,$A4)<5,SEARCH(D$3,$A4)-1,2)),0)*1`
- Formula in **E4** & fill down:

  `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E$3,$A4)),MID($A4,IF(SEARCH(E$3,$A4)<5,1,SEARCH(E$3,$A4)-2),IF(SEARCH(E$3,$A4)<5,SEARCH(E$3,$A4)-1,2)),0)*1`
- Final Formula in **F4**:

`=IF(LEN(A4)>1,B4+C4/24+D4/(24*60)+E4/(24*60^2),"")`

**N.B.**

- Adjust cell references in the Formula as 
  needed.
- Cell Format for Range `A4:E29` is 
  `GENERAL`.
- Cell Format for Range `F4:F29` is 
  `[h]:mm:ss`.
- *You can hide Helper Columns as soon you 
  get the job done.*

Comment: These are all really good ideas. I’ll test them out, particularly non-code ones since I need to keep the file simple for those who inherit the file later on

Comment: @Rox,, glad to help you,, I've tried to include as many example I can,, follow instructions properly, you also find is working. ☺